# Cannot use CC for teams - what to do

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

My company doesn't allow us to use our personal cards for software expenses...so I cannot use my credit card.  It appears my company would need to create a purchase order and enter vendor information into our ERP system to proceed.

Before I go to my purchasing group I wanted to ask...is there any other way to go with "Teams" for SO not using a credit card?  In addition, they want to use a purchase order and allow us to pay in this method.

Can we do this over the phone?  I ask because we'd be looking at only the annual $120 fee we are not an enterprise customer.  Help me help you before they force me to look into another tool!  Several emails have asked me to look elsewhere and I'd actually hate to because I'd prefer using SO for Teams.

The linked duplicate asks to basically not pay but to just try "Teams" what I am saying is we'd like to pay but not via personal credit card.  We are looking to open a purchase request to allow stackoverflow to bill us.  But I don't believe we can do this online with the current setup.  We'd need to call someone there?

Answer (score 0):

**At this time credit cards are the only form of payment we accept for Stack Overflow for Teams.**

We are considering adding options for invoicing based payments in the future - however even in these cases it would likely be limited to accounts of a certain size, using our invoicing portal (not yours), etc.

We're also considering other options like PayPal - but don't expect us to add Bitcoin anytime soon.

Comment: You guys are really cornering yourselves into this solution.  I can say that we cannot for sure use it if that is the only payment method.  This should have been something you guys brought to the table before releasing it as you can lose customers to other tools - such as my case.  Sorry to see this.

Comment: @JonH it would be great to support every payment method, but unfortunately things like invoicing add a ton of overhead to the process.  That's why most services either don't offer it, or if they do, only offer it if you're committed annually and spending above a threshold

Comment: We're committed annually so why can't I get a person on the phone and we take care of this?  This doesn't make sense.

Comment: alex any chance you can shoot me your email address?